# Trouble updating blog app in Express and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a blog site using CRUD operations. I can create, read and delete but am having a hard time with figuring out how to update a created post. Basically I have it where I can click on the "edit" button on an individual entry in **home.ejs** and into the **edit.ejs** route where that input fields are populated with current title and content. I want to be able edit the content and title, then click "Publish" on the **edit.ejs** route to update the content. But when I do that, it gives me an error: **Cannot POST /edit** and nothing updates. What I want it to do is update an individual entry, then redirect back to the root route and have the edit reflected. Down on the "app.post("/edit/:id")" route, am I supposed to use "PUT" request to update the post? I'm sorry if this is tough to follow. I'm not very good at explaining things. I've been racking my brain on this for a while. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the relevant code:

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

let app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blogDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const postSchema = {
  date: String,
  title: String,
  content: String
}

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {

  Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
    res.render("home", {
      posts: posts
    });
  });
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about", {
    aboutContent: aboutContent
  });
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact", {
    contactContent: contactContent
  });
});

app.get("/compose", (req, res) => {
  res.render("compose");
});


app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  const postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
  const postBody = req.body.postBody;

  let date = new Date();
  let postDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US');

  const post = new Post({
    date: postDate,
    title: postTitle,
    content: postBody
  });

  post.save(err => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.get("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body);
  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedId
  }, (err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body);
  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedId
  }, (err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});



app.get("/posts/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;

  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedId
  }, (err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("post", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
  const deletePost = req.body.delete;

  Post.findByIdAndDelete(deletePost, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**home.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>
<h1>Home</h1>
<a href="/compose" class="post-link"><button type="button" class="new-entry btn btn-dark">New Entry</button></a>

<div class="entries-container">
  <% posts.forEach(post => { %>

  <div class="blog-entry">
    <p class="post-date">Posted on
      <%= post.date %>
    </p>
    <h2>
      <%= post.title %>
    </h2>
    <div class="entry-footer">
      <a href="/posts/<%= post._id %>" class="post-link"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">VIEW</button></a>
      <form action="/edit" method="POST">
        <a href="/edit/<%= post._id %>" class="post-link" ><button type="button" name="edit" value="<%= post.title %>" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">EDIT</button></a>
      </form>
      <form action="/delete" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="delete" value="<%= post._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% }) %>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

**edit.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>
<h1>Compose</h1>
<form action="/edit" method="PUT">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="postTitle">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="postTitle" class="form-control" id="postTitle" autocomplete="off" value="<%= title %>">
    <label for="postBody">Post</label>
    <textarea name="postBody" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" rows="8"><%= content %></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</form>
<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

**post.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>
  <h2 class="post-title"><%= title %></h2>
  <p class="post-content"><%= content %></p>
<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

Comment: If anyone needs clarification, let me know. But I really need some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

typically you would use `PUT` if you are making an update and `POST` if you are creating a new item, but in all honesty, those words don't force behavior, rather the code you write would.

from your code, you have a get and a post declared on /edit/: id which is not necessarily wrong, but both of them have the same code.

If I was making a blog post editor, I would define my routes as follows:

`GET - /blog` -- get all the blogs

`GET - /blog/:id` -- get a single blogs

`POST - /blog` -- create a new blog

`PUT - /blog/:id` -- update an existing blog

`DELETE - /blog/:id` -- delete an existing blog

As for your form, you have the action set to PUT, but you don't have a corresponding PUT route declared in your express application.

In mongoose, the easiest way to update an existing item is to use `.findOne()` and in the callback function to change your object as needed then call `.save()`

Comment: Thanks, but it's still giving me a similar error: "Cannot PUT /edit." Basically I am trying to pass the updated inputs data from "edit.ejs" route onto the existing blog's route.

Comment: you need to write an app.put('/edit', (req,res)=>{ /*code here*/}); handler